# Why flash plugin is not updating?

Tags: debian, adobe-flash

I'm running Debian Jessie. I've upgraded the system with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then I try to update flash-plugin with:

```
sudo update-flashplugin-nonfree --install
```

But the command runs without output and the plugin is not updated.

```
sudo update-flashplugin-nonfree --status
```

gives:

```
Flash Player version installed on this system  : 11.2.202.577
Flash Player version available on upstream site: 11.2.202.616
flash-mozilla.so - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so - priority 50
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so'.
```

If I reinstall `flashplugin-nonfree` with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-nonfree
```

the same problem occurs.

What is the problem?

== Edit (June 7, 2016 )==

This is a recurring problem, running:

```
sudo update-flashplugin-nonfree --install
sudo update-flashplugin-nonfree --status
```

gives

```
Flash Player version installed on this system  : 11.2.202.616
Flash Player version available on upstream site: 11.2.202.621
```

This problem is [already reported](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=814316#67).

I know that it's never safe to run flash player but debian distribution should help to mitigate this risk for those who need to rely on flash player.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to update to  the `11.2.202.616` version of flash, correct? Consider using the pepper flash version instead. What browser are you using? See `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` and `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash`.

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove security vulnerabilities by updating `flash-plugin`. And in fact, this should be updated with regular package upgrade.

Comment: Don't forget to close all applications using flash player before updating

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The update signatures [aren't available yet](https://people.debian.org/~bartm/flashplugin-nonfree/D5C0FC14/); `flashplugin-nonfree` checks these to make sure the files being installed are OK (*i.e.* you're not downloading corrupted files). [A bug already exists for this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=814316), you need to wait for the maintainer to react (or install the plugin manually).

Comment: If you have to use flash, this is a major security issue. But it's solved for now. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=814316#32

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why the flashplugin-nonfree isn't updating, but I have one solution:

1. First, install the flashplugin: sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
2. Then, download the latest version of flash from adobe site (https://get.adobe.com/br/flashplayer/otherversions/) .. USE .TAR.GZ version!
3. Extract the file libflashplayer.so from the tar.gz and put it on /usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree , replacing the older one.
4. Check if you have the latest version working: sudo update-flashplugin-nonfree --status
5. Enjoy!

Comment: I tried doing this, but when I go to sites using Flash, it still says, "Iceweasel has prevented the outdated plugin Adobe Flash from running on <site name>." The command update-flashplugin-nonfree --status stated that "Flash Player version installed on this system  : 11.2.202.621
Flash Player version available on upstream site: 11.2.202.621
"Is rebooting the machine necessary after the install?

Comment: @Kelmikra Should work if you just restart your browser.

Comment: @DmitriDB I did. Edit: Oddly enough, it did not fix the problem when I restarted the browser before, but it did after I restarted it now.

Comment: @Felipe Thanks for the workaround, works like a charm!